# My current location and updated location in Google Maps is not showing

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to show my current location and update it when I move. But the problem is the **blue dot** where it indicates my current location is not showing. (but the map is showing)

I tried these codes below and it is not showing my location (with a blue dot). **It only shows just the map**

Here is my `MapsActivity.java`

can someone tell me where I have gone wrong? Why is it not showing?

```
package com.example.jananathbanuka.sliitshuttle;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener {

    GoogleMap mMap;
    GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
    Location lastLocation;
    LocationRequest locationRequest;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        buildGoogleApiClient();
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        locationRequest.setInterval(1000); //1 second
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000); //1 second
        locationRequest.setPriority(locationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, locationRequest, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPointerCaptureChanged(boolean hasCapture) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        lastLocation = location;
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(12));
    }

    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient(){
        googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
        .addConnectionCallbacks(this).addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
        .addApi(LocationServices.API)
        .build();

        googleApiClient.connect();
    }
}
```

Comment: try to put mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true); this code exact below mMap = googleMap; and try again, sometimes due to exception, it is possible that this line could not execute it self.

Comment: @ArjunVyas it doesn't allow to put it right below the **mMap = googleMap;** It shows error and needs to be right below the exception